# Defining an "envelope contour" without specifying a time window (zoom level)

Tags: acoustics

One of the most fundamental terms one hears in the field of acoustics is that of the amplitude envelope, aka the contour, aka the envelope contour. Intuitively this is easy to grasp as the area formed by connecting the peaks of a sound's waveform.

However, exactly how those points are to be connected in creating an envelope seems to me to depend on some time or zoom constant that I never see reported when reading about envelopes. Surely the definition of a peak relates to how much to its left and right you "look", and similarly, how you connect those peaks should also depend on something like this - no?

To illustrate this, I've included screenshots from a sound waveform, viewed at three different zoom levels, from the most outward to the most inward (detailed):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I am misunderstanding your question but...

From a practical point of view the envelope is related to the power spectrum.  The picture you show is of the pulse in time, time-domain representation. If we were doing signal processing on this we would slice small windows of the signal, pass the data in to an FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) with a window function to reduce side lobes, Then look for peaks in the frequency spectrum.  One can relate the amplitude of the signal to the size of the FFT peak, Parseval's theorem.  This can be done for each and every frequency in the spectrum.  The window can then be slid over the time-domain data to do the analysis again.  This gets tricky as you will likely have (1) impulses from instruments being attacked, (2) and a mixture of multiple sources contributing to each frequency bin.

If you want to just trace out what appears to be the max peaks of your waveform then I think your description may be on the right track, you need a good peak finder that can locate local max/min and not get confused.  For example, the same thing is needed in the frequency-domain to find frequency peaks. Connecting peaks in the time domain should not depend on anything but the data you have.  You look for points where the slope changes sign or some other test, and keep those points stored.  Once your are complete, connect those dots and you should have an envelope that encompasses the waveform, following the apparent contour.  You will have to distinguish min from max, or assume symmetry and look for peaks in the abs val of the wave.

Comment: Thanks, this gets close to what I was intending to ask (I agree the question is confusing, and perhaps not well-posed). The envelope I was asking about is indeed in the time domain, not in the freq domain. In any domain however (regardless of what the x axis represents, time or freq), connecting peaks seems to me to imply arbitrariness, for instance how wide a vicinity do you define a peak to be. But you mention zero-crossing, which seems to be an absolute (non-arbitrary) way to base such a definition on, so I guess the answer I am looking for is in that direction!

Comment: Yes, searching for a zero derivative is the peak.  If your data is sparsely sampled (sparse but not necessarily under sampled severe enough to alias) your max will not be at the "peak" but you can (1) interpolate, or (2) use a best fit quadratic near the estimated max and that will do very well.

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive way to understand constructing the envelope is to consider a monochromatic sine wave, then extend the concepts to an arbitrary signal that can be decomposed into monochromatic sinusoids via the fourier transform.

Consider the trig identity: $sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1$. This represents a sine function that is duplicated, shifted by 90 degrees ($sin(x+\pi/2)=cos(x)$), squared, and summed. It is no coincidence that the envelope of a sine wave is 1 (the result of the above identity).

Now extend this to an arbitrary signal. Decompose the signal into it's individual sinusoidal components via the fourier transform, shift all frequencies by 90 degree phase, and add the squares. Transforming the result back to the time domain (inverse fourier transform) will give you the envelope of the input signal, with no need to further define time windows or zoom levels (outside of the intial window when computing the fourier transform).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform